# Maven - resolving "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors"

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, java, maven

I am attempting to build/install this project on an Ubuntu 12.04 box:

https://bitbucket.org/petermr/pdf2svg

However:

```
mvn clean install
```

Fails to build due to getting errors like this:

```
Downloading: https://maven.ch.cam.ac.uk/m2repo/org/xml-cml/euclid/1.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.xml-cml:euclid:1.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to ucc-repo (https://maven.ch.cam.ac.uk/m2repo): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
```

Based on some Google searching, the message apparently has something to do with SSL certificates, but the meaning of the error message eludes me, let alone how to fix this problem.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to that issue?